# Django model - how to display class' property with foreign key in rest api

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

serializers.py:

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=[
            'author',
            'title',
            'content',
            'likes',
        ]
```

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    logged_in=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        self.full_name=self.name+' '+self.surname
        return self.full_name


class Post(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content=models.TextField()
    likes=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My question is,

How would I display author.name from Post model class in Rest API via serializer, since serilizer fields take literal parameter name from the given class?

Comment: Maybe nested serializers can help? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: I don't think it could help me anyhow, or I don't know how to implement it? Any example?

Comment: Another option could be to use a SerializerMethodField named whatever you want, with a get_field_name method that grabs the value you want through the relationship. I'm on mobile right now, but I'll post an answer when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a read-only field, a `SerializerMethodField` should do the trick. Try the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.author.name

    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=[
            'author',
            'title',
            'content',
            'likes',
        ]
```

Comment: I tried this, and this is the error I got `'PostSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_author'`

Comment: Ups, my bad. It works fine. I wrote something bad in the code. Thank You, Sir!

Comment: No problem! Happy django-ing!